# Remove key from AJAX data if empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have an ajax with the data array 
This is my object

```
   var question_data = {

            ambiguity_in_answer: ambiguity_in_answer,
            bug_ids: {
           range: Range,
            this: notAH,
            for: have,
            }
```

```
data: {
  range: Range,
            this: notAH,
            for: have,
},
```

What I want is to remove the key from data if their values are "  ". So whenever a user submits the form if any data field is empty it should be deleted from json data before sending and key having values should proceed as normal.

I tried doing this in ajax

```
beforeSend: function (key, value) {
                return (value == "") ? delete(key) : value
            },
```

Comment: If you are downvoting Please comment why ? . SO that i would search somewhere else

Comment: Probably because you've not shown any code or attempt. People treat Stackoverflow as a code writing service which it isn't. Show us what you've tried, there's plenty of articles on here how to filter arrays.

Comment: i have added what is was doing

Comment: You need more in there. How do you construct your object that you then send?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you

```
var data = [
    { "name": "bill", "age": 20 },
    { "name": "jhon", "age": 19 },
    { "name": "steve", "age": 16 },
    { "name": "larry", "age": 22 },
      null, null, null
   ];
//eliminate all the null values from the data
  data = data.filter(function(x) { return x !== null });
  console.log("data: " + JSON.stringify(data));
```